# How to implement pagination of JSON state object in React after it loads

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

In React have a JSON returning strings that I want to be able to slice and use only the first six objects. I can return all the JSON at once and render it just fine but I want to be to call just some of them. Like the first six and use [Infinite Scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component) to return the next six. I don't need an answer for how to setup infinite scroll, I just need the JSON, `apiResponse` state object to load in a way I can use to just be able to call parts of it.

The JSON is being returned from my server side in Express and it looks like this...

```
[{"image":"https://www.fakeimageurl.com/3456","post":"http://www.urltothefakeimage/4554"},  
{"image":"https://www.fakeimageurl.com/3456","post":"http://www.urltothefakeimage/4554"},  
{"image":"https://www.fakeimageurl.com/3456","post":"http://www.urltothefakeimage/4554"}, 
{"image":"https://www.fakeimageurl.com/3456","post":"http://www.urltothefakeimage/4554"} <... etc.>]
```

When I say I want the first six, I mean I want the first six elements in curly braces each with its `image` and `post` link.
My attempt to load it below. Now I am only able to have it load everything at once. Though here I tried to have it loaded and stored in `componentDidUpdate`. I want to store the JSON elements and grab bits of it.

The JSON is first requested with the function `callAPI()`.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Fb_grid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      apiResponse: ""
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.callAPI();
}

callAPI() {
    fetch('/api/getList')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }))
}
componentDidUpdate() {
  this.setState({ apiResponse: Object.values(apiResponse).map((value, index) => 
    value.post, value.image )})
}
  render() {
    /* Extract apiResponse object */
    const { apiResponse } = this.state;

    /* Assume that while apiResponse matches initial state, the fetch
    request is still busy, so render a loading message */
    if(!apiResponse) {
        return <p className="row">Loading</p>
    }
    return(
      <div className="App">
      <div class="row">
        {(apiResponse).map((value, index) => 
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={value.post}>
          <img src={value.image} className="image"/>
        </a>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

If you got rid of `componentDidUpdate` and return this instead of the code above the component will read the JSON just fine and render the images and provide them links with `value.post`.

```
return(
  <div className="App">
  <div class="row">
    {Object.values(apiResponse).map((value, index) => 
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={value.post}>
      <img src={value.image} className="image"/>
    </a>)}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: You should use pagination on your API call.

Comment: "use pagination on your API call". Would that call the API every time I need the next six? Would that happen in componentDidMount or in another function?

Comment: Given a classical pagination experience, on the first page's load, you get the first six elements. Then when the user clicks on the "next" button, you fetch the next six elements and so on (or obviously using the infinite scroll library).

Comment: I think my first issue is that I don't know how I get React to store the whole JSON in the state object. I want one call to the API for all whole JSON and I want to write a function that can grab parts of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read only the first 6 items from your JSON, you can use the following code.

```js
callAPI() {
    fetch('/api/getList')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res.slice(0, 6) }))
}
```

Instead, if you want to display the elements 6 by 6, you will need a `next` and `previous` buttons probably, calling these callbacks:

```js
next() {
  this.setState({ page: this.state.page+1 }))
}
previous() {
  this.setState({ page: this.state.page-1 }))
}
```

Now, to display the elements 6 by 6, you only need to do this in your render to render only the current page:

```js
this.state.apiResponse.slice(this.state.page*6, (this.state.page+1)*6)
```

Of course, you need to disable the `next` and `previous` buttons when you reach the start or the end. It could be a good idea also to safeproof your `next` and `previous` functions to ensure you can't go out of bounds:

```js
next() {
  this.setState({ page: Math.min(this.state.apiResponse.length-1, this.state.page+1) }))
}
previous() {
  this.setState({ page: Math.max(0, this.state.page-1) }))
}
```

Comment: "I'm not sure that I understood your question". I want the first six elements and then the next six and then the next six. Thank you for this solution but I think this might make a request to the API on my backend over and over when I could probably grab the whole JSON, store it, and use pieces of it. My problem is 1: storing the JSON somewhere and 2: being able to grab six elements at a time. Store it and use it. I don't know how to have it stored in the state in a way I can use it. I'm getting non specific errors when I try.

Comment: Do you prefer ask the elements 6 by 6 to your server or do you want to load everything and only display 6 by 6?

Comment: "load everything and only display 6 by 6?" This. Just 6 images at a time. I would think if all images to possibly be used were loaded into React first it would load faster and make less requests to the API serving the JSON to my backend. Looking at it now, I think I should put the `Object.values(apiResponse).map` in its own function maybe that is keeping count somehow.

Comment: I'm sure this answer will go toward solving the problem, but maybe I got ahead of myself. How can I store/ use the entire JSON list of URLs in the state object in a way that I can use it as if it was a JSON I wrote in the component? I want the JSON all at once and to be able to grab parts of it. As it is now I get the 'loading' screen and it renders the objects after they eventually load. I though `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` would have set it in the state and I would be able to use it but I get errors that it doesn't exist when I try to slice it in functions.

Comment: You need to initialize your state: `this.state = {apiResponse: [], page: 0}`

Comment: There is a problem in your question, though. You say that the response of the server is an Array, but in the render, you call `Object.values` on it...

Comment: That's how it displays on the screen if instead of fetching it with `.then(res => res.json())` I get it with `.then(res => res.text())` and render the whole object to the page. If you look at the bottom of my question I showed what makes the code work. I mean, it works using `.values`. As you might have guessed I'm new to grabbing a whole JSON object like this in React and making use of it.

Comment: Then what is the issue if you use my code, remove the componentDidUpdate, and replace Object.values(apiResponse) by apiRespoinse?

Comment: I think I applied your code and it's working ideally as I wanted it to. Sorry, like I said, I'm new to React and I didn't know where those lines you wrote go. I see the `callAPI()` function you adjusted (which makes a call for 6 items each time) isn't related to the bottom two blocks of code. The last two bits of code do exactly what I need. Namely using everything returned from the API once and enabling the DOM to load more instantly.

Comment: Though I tried just now putting the next() function in a button just now `<button onClick={this.next}></button>` but I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` when I click it. I set `this.state = {apiResponse: [], page: 0}` in the constructor.

Comment: Hold on! Okay, fixed that problem by adding `this.next.bind(this)` EVERYTHING WORKS NOW. Thank you so much! I gave you an upvote btw but someone gave you a downvote for some reason. Just fyi.

Comment: Don't worry. I'm glad if it helped and it's great that you finished the job by yourself. It means you probably learned a lot already ;)